# phpBB LDAP login - bind failed

Tags: php, ldap, phpbb

I'm trying to set up login with LDAP to a PhpBB forum. I have problems with setting up connection to AD. I have server name, server port, base dn (looks like - dc=test dc=com, because domain is test.com), uid, user dn, and user password.

I don't understand why I have to put user dn and password because there are about 900 users that will login? And I'm getting error that bind failed.

Answer (score 1):

The User DN  and password is for the Administrative account.

Thus, the base DN is where all searches will begin.  The user will enter an identifier to login.  This is mapped to uid, in your selection.  Then the admin specified user will try to find a user whose `(uid=EntereduserIdentifier)` and it will then get the DN of that object, and finally try to bind as that full DN, and the user provided password.

Comment: I solved everything last night but now I have another problem. I want to change display name and I found mod that separates login name and username. When I change username, I can't login. When I'm trying to login with another user from domain (not stored as forum user in database), phpBB says that it can't create user profile. Anyone know why this is happaning?